# What permissions do i have to choose when using fine-grained Token in Github

Tags: github, permissions, github-fine-grained-tokens

First of all im using macbook m1.

Im trying to push to an repository in organization made by my friend.
My friend added me to the repository which im trying to push as a contributor.
And i succeeded to push the repository when using Windows OS.

When i tried to push first to the repository with classic token, I got this error

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.

so... i was reminded to change the token from classic token to fine-grained personal token.

[image]

That's how i made the fine-grained personal token.
But i got an different error.

this:
remote: Permission to GotPrgmer/co-re-study.git denied to GotPrgmer.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/GotPrgmer/co-re-study.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

What can i do for solving this problem?

Thank you

Changed the Token from classic token to fine-grained token

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.

I skipped git add and git commit after regenerating token.
After cloning newly the repository, i executed git add . , git commit -m "asdf" and so on, then push command worked.